# $\tan(\arcsin x)$ if $x\gt0 $

Tags: trigonometry

I drew a triangle with $1$ as the hypotenuse and $x$ as the side opposite of sine. I'm getting a blank on how to get the bottom part of the triangle.

Would the bottom side just be $\cos\theta$? i.e.,

$$\tan \theta=  x/a$$

$$ a= \sin x /\tan x $$

$$a=\cos x?$$

Comment: Pythagorean theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\arcsin x=u$

$\implies\sin u=x$ and

$-\dfrac\pi2\le u\le\dfrac\pi2\implies\cos u=+\sqrt{1-\sin^2u}=?$

$\tan(\arcsin x)=\tan u=\dfrac{\sin u}{\cos u}$

Answer (score 1):

As an earlier comment says, you want to use Pythagoras:

[image]

It should be clear from this image... say if you need more guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Draw the right triangle.Calculate all sides and label them.Now you are ready to evaluate any trig function of inverse trig funtion.Proceed from inside to outside always during evaluation.

$$ \sin \alpha = \frac{x}{1} $$

$$ \tan \alpha = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} $$

$$ arctan \, \tan \alpha = arctan \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} $$

$$ \alpha = arctan \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}. $$